# One Day Bitcoin Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, bitcoin

I'm trying to build a Bitcoin graph with a history of one day. I'm building it with Javascript and highCharts, But the target should be for a free iPhone App that presents the last day chart of the Bitcoin values.

I have found openchart API which is pretty easy but I can't find any source that I can change the values dynamically (I need dynamically chart with Bitcoin values from the last hour).

**Here is what I did (I put it as a static data):**

```
var wikiMonthsCovered = ["14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00",
                         "20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00","00:00","01:00",
                         "02:00","03:00"];
var wikiHistoryStats = [{"name":"Bitcoin","data":[180,178,177,176,175,174,173,
                                                  172,171,175,176,180,190,220]}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujLg5/2/

The problem is that all values are static in this Chart, 
I thought to create it in a web page and then load it to the app, but, of course, any other suggestion (API or script) will be great!

Comment: The only question mark is in the title and it is unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: the question is: how can i build current bitcoin value chart with one day back, for iphone app? thanks

Comment: Check Highcharts demos, for example this one: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle example of live updating graphs: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/Pxh4f/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting an official answer so people can see that this question has been answered in the search/tag list.

- Check Highcharts demos, for example this one: highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update - [Paul Fus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451635/pawel-fus)
- Here is a jsFiddle example of live updating graphs: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/Pxh4f/) - [Benedict Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2078412/benedict-lewis)

Additional Resources:

```
Highchart Demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/
Highchart API Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts
Changelog: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog
```